# How to extract the repeatable part of lucene query?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have 4 fields, docContent, visibility, docOwner and docType. I want to get all *docType:ProfileDocument* except those with *visibility:1*. But the owner of each document can say that his document with *visibility:1* can be returned from the search result. The query bellow searches for *asd*, returning all documents that matches the term and their visibility is not 1 except for *docOwner:390*. The query works but the **docType:ProfileDocument** is repeated twice. How to refactor the query so **docType:ProfileDocument** be presented only once?

```
docContent:asd
AND(
    (NOT visibility:1 AND docType:ProfileDocument)
    OR ( docOwner:390 AND visibility:1 AND docType:ProfileDocument)
)
```

I tried this but I failed:

```
docContent:asd
AND(
    (((NOT visibility:1)
    OR ( docOwner:390 AND visibility:1))
    AND docType:ProfileDocument)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AND NOT operator cannot be used with just one term. For example, the following search will return no results:

AND NOT "jakarta apache"

Reference: http://drupal.org/node/375446